# Error using CASE expression as column alias, SUM, GROUP BY, and subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum, case

I have two table: *Orders*, and *ODetail*. I want to create a table that shows the sum of sales of year 2012 grouped by year, quarter and productline (which is a case). Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT 
YEAR(o.OrderDate) 'Year', DATEPART(Quarter, o.OrderDate) 'Quarter',
                    CASE 
                    WHEN SUBSTRING (od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'M' THEN 'Motors'
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNUM, 4, 1)= 'T' THEN 'Trolling Motors'
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'P' THEN 'Pumps'
                END  ProductLine,
                SUM(od.QPrice*od.Quantity)




FROM Orders o, ODetail od
WHERE o.OrderNum=od.OrderNum
AND YEAR(o.OrderDate)=2012

)a

GROUP BY a.Year, a.Quarter, a.ProductLine
```

For some reason, I still get an error related to GROUP BY. the Query works just fine when I try to group all columns except the SUM column. Any ideas?

Comment: In general, it is also helpful to include any error text (as opposed to "I get *an error*"), and also describe what alternatives you have tried (I mention this because you used the word "still"). This will guide any answerers, as well as help everyone understand the problem in case they have the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this without a subquery:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(o.OrderDate) AS [Year],
    DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate) AS [Quarter],
    CASE
        WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'M' THEN 'Motors'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNUM, 4, 1)= 'T' THEN 'Trolling Motors'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'P' THEN 'Pumps' 
    END AS ProductLine,
    SUM(od.QPrice * od.Quantity)
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Odetail od
    ON o.OrderNum = od.OrderNum
WHERE
    o.OrderDate >= CAST('20120101' AS DATE)
    AND o.OrderDate < CAST('20130101' AS DATE)
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(o.OrderDate), 
    DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate),
    CASE
        WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'M' THEN 'Motors'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNUM, 4, 1)= 'T' THEN 'Trolling Motors'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'P' THEN 'Pumps' 
    END
```

---

Note: Avoid using old-style `JOIN` syntax. Read this [**article**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: It worked! Yet I still don't get why in the WHERE clause you had to CAST because the simple WHERE Year(o.orderdate)= 2012 did not work actually

Comment: I don't know why `YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2012` did not work for you. But using `YEAR()` on the `where` clause would make the query non-sargable.

Comment: Now, I tried `WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, o.OrderDate)=2012` and that worked too.

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` will inform what columns are grouped and applied to the aggregate function, in this case `SUM`. It will be easier to see the error if you consider your inner query (that you aliased `a`) as an individual query. Then, you will see that you have a `SUM` but no `GROUP BY`.

When you `GROUP BY` the columns `Year, Quarter, ProductLine` you are saying "select multiple rows that match a year, quarter, and product line, but then roll them up and sum the value of `Price*Quantity`".

So, you could put the `GROUP BY` with the inner query:

```
SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT 
YEAR(o.OrderDate) 'Year', DATEPART(Quarter, o.OrderDate) 'Quarter',
                    CASE 
                    WHEN SUBSTRING (od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'M' THEN 'Motors'
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNUM, 4, 1)= 'T' THEN 'Trolling Motors'
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'P' THEN 'Pumps'
                END  ProductLine,
                SUM(od.QPrice*od.Quantity)




FROM Orders o, ODetail od
WHERE o.OrderNum=od.OrderNum
AND YEAR(o.OrderDate)=2012
GROUP BY Year, Quarter, ProductLine

)a
```

Which A) makes the inner query redundant, and B) will probably complain about not having a column called `Year` or `ProductLine`. This is probably why you used an inner query. You will have to repeat the field definition inline:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(o.OrderDate), DATEPART(Quarter, o.OrderDate), CASE 
                    WHEN SUBSTRING (od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'M' THEN 'Motors'
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNUM, 4, 1)= 'T' THEN 'Trolling Motors'
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'P' THEN 'Pumps'
                END
```

Or you could (shudder) group by column position aliases:

```
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Caution: the column aliases will change if your query changes, and may not be very maintainable, but work well for ad hoc queries.

Lastly, instead of moving the `GROUP BY` inside, you could move the `SUM` outside:

```
SELECT a.Year, a.Quarter, a.ProductLine, SUM(a.QPrice*a.Quantity) FROM 

(SELECT 
YEAR(o.OrderDate) 'Year', DATEPART(Quarter, o.OrderDate) 'Quarter',
                    CASE 
                    WHEN SUBSTRING (od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'M' THEN 'Motors'
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNUM, 4, 1)= 'T' THEN 'Trolling Motors'
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(od.PNum, 4, 1)= 'P' THEN 'Pumps'
                END  ProductLine,
                od.QPrice,
                od.Quantity




FROM Orders o, ODetail od
WHERE o.OrderNum=od.OrderNum
AND YEAR(o.OrderDate)=2012

) a

GROUP BY a.Year, a.Quarter, a.ProductLine
```

Note you'll have to avoid selecting `*` so that you can separate the grouped columns from the aggregate columns, and be sure to include the columns you are aggregating in your inner query.